JsSip Call: remoteMediaStream doesn't work if I do not use auto answer. How to fix it?
 const answerMethod = () => {
          stopSound();
          return data.session.answer({
            pcConfig: peerConstraints,
            mediaStream: mediaStream,
            mediaConstraints: mediaConstraints,
          });
        };

        onAnswerHandler(answerMethod, data.session);

        callSessionDataRef.current = data.session;

        let remoteMediaStream;

        data.session.on('addstream', (e: any) => {
          console.log('============= addstream ', e.stream);
          setStatusCallState(StatusCall.ADDSTREAM);
        });

        data?.session?.connection &&
          data.session.connection.addEventListener('track', event => {
            if (data.session.isEstablished()) {
              // Grab the remote track from the connected participant.
              remoteMediaStream = remoteMediaStream || new MediaStream();
              remoteMediaStream.addTrack(event.track, remoteMediaStream);

              setRemoteStream(remoteMediaStream);

              console.log('$$$$$$$$$$$$$', event.track);
            }
          });

        return;
      });

If I use answerMethod immediately, then I'm able to see a picture from caller, but If I use answerMethod for a button to answer a call, then I do not see any picture from caller
